# Decoding/parsing specific JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am having a lot of trouble trying to decode this JSON with Swift 4.

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 1525680450507,
            "animal": "bee",
            "type": "insect",
            "diet": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1,
    "ScannedCount": 5
}
```

Here's where I try to decode

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = try decoder.decode([Animal].self, from: data)
```

I have created a struct like this

```
struct Animal: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var animal: String
    var type: String
    var diet: [String]
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = try decoder.decode(ItemsResponse.self, from: data)
```

This doesn't work. I get an error that says

> "Expected to decode Array<\Any>  but found a dictionary instead."

So I thought maybe I needed something like this

```
struct ItemsResponse: Codable {
    var Items: [Animal]
    var Count: Int
    var ScannedCount: Int
}
```

But this doesn't work either. Now I get

> "Expected to decode Array<\Any> but found a string/data instead."

How do I make a struct that will decode this JSON?

Comment: With the last 2 pieces of codes you gave, I got it work on Playground. Maybe you are trying on "real JSON" (not only that sample), and there is a optional value (different kind of value if not found for instance).

Comment: your code is right, it is working on my side

Comment: That's the response I'm getting back from postman and when I print out the json I get back in Swift, it looks the same. But I'll still be getting an error. The full error is this         Err typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "diet", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Ohhh, it's because in the Items array I have other objects that don't have diet as an array of strings, it was just 1 string. I only posted one of the examples. Once I corrected that, everything worked. Thanks for confirming my code worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = try decoder.decode([Animal].self, from: data)
```

`[Animal].self` is not correct you can use it like this :

```
struct DataJson: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
    let count, scannedCount: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items = "Items"
        case count = "Count"
        case scannedCount = "ScannedCount"
    }
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let animal, type: String
    let diet: [String]
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension DataJson {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataJson.self, from: data)
    }



    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

extension Item {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
    }


    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```swift
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "id": 1525680450507,
            "animal": "bee",
            "type": "insect",
            "diet": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1,
    "ScannedCount": 5
}
"""

struct Animal: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var animal: String
    var type: String
    var diet: [String]
}

struct ItemsResponse: Codable {
    var Items: [Animal]
    var Count: Int
    var ScannedCount: Int
}

let data = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ItemsResponse.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Of course, you should properly handle the possible failures (i.e. don't do `try!`, and don't force-unwrapp the `json.data()!` part)

But the code above works and hopefully answers your question.